# Pyinstaller - getting multiple exe files in a single compilation

Tags: python, pyinstaller, python-3.7

I wanted to have multiple .exe files with common used libraries. for example, I have a project that should have `a.py` and `b.py` and both these scripts use another script like `c.py`
so I should have `a.exe` and `b.exe`.

curently i can get this like this:

```
pyinstaller a.py
```

and then

```
pyinstaller b.py
```

and after that copy contents of `dist\a` to `dist\b` and replace them so I will have both `a.exe` and `b.exe` in the same place without duplication of other compiled libraries. Is there a way to do this with a single command like `pyinstaller a.py,b.py`?

Comment: Did you do any research, for example reading the PyInstaller documentation? What does that say about using PyInstaller?

Comment: well I could'nt find anything about this approach, the only things mentioned in docs explains how can make an standalone .exe file or other questions in SO are about combining multiple .py files into a single .exe file which is not what I want thats why I asked this Q

Answer (score 2):

I just solved this problem that was bothering me.

you can make some `.spec` file and merge them, and run pyinstaller to build multi exe.

- generate a spec file for each python file that you want build to exe.

```
pyi-makespec xxx.py
```

generated `.spec` file just like this:

```
a = Analysis(...)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data, ...)
exe = EXE(pyz,a.scripts, ...)
coll = COLLECT(exe,a.binaries, ...)
```

- change variable name, just like this:

```
main = Analysis(...)
main_pyz = PYZ(main.pure, main.zipped_data, ...)
main_exe = EXE(main_pyz,main.scripts, ...)
coll = COLLECT(main_exe,main.binaries, ...)
```

- process all `.spec` files like this and merge the contents of
  coll into one

```
main = Analysis(...)
main_pyz = PYZ(main.pure, main.zipped_data, ...)
main_exe = EXE(main_pyz, main.scripts, ...)
sub = Analysis(...)
sub_pyz = PYZ(sub.pure, sub.zipped_data, ...)
sub_exe = EXE(sub_pyz, sub.scripts, ...)
...
coll = COLLECT(main_exe, sub_exe, ...)
```

- finally, build it with the pyinstaller

```
pyinstller xxx.spec
```